# Spectrum of the infinite biregular tree (with an example)

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-theory, random-walk, spectral-graph-theory

This question concerns the spectrum of the universal covers of graphs. In particular, some results in:

1. Angel, Omer; Friedman, Joel; Hoory, Shlomo The non-backtracking spectrum of the universal cover of a graph. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 367 (2015), no. 6, and
2. Nagnibeda, Tatiana Random walks, spectral radii, and Ramanujan graphs. Random walks and geometry, 487–500, Walter de Gruyter, Berlin, 2004 .

It's well known that in the case of infinite $k$-regular trees the spectrum is:
$$
[-2 \sqrt{k-1}, 2 \sqrt{k-1}] .
$$
Moreover, in the case of an infinite $(k,l)$-biregular tree the spectrum is:
$$
\{ \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\ \big| \  |\sqrt{k - 1} - \sqrt{ l - 1} |\leq |\lambda| \leq |\sqrt{k - 1} + \sqrt{ l - 1} |  \} \cup \{ 0\}\ ,
$$
as one can see, for example, in

- Mohar, Bojan; Woess, Wolfgang A survey on spectra of infinite graphs. Bull. London Math. Soc. 21 (1989), and
- Li, Wen-Ch'ing Winnie; Solé, Patrick Spectra of regular graphs and hypergraphs and orthogonal polynomials. European J. Combin. 17 (1996) .

However, very little is known about the spectrum of the universal cover of irregular graphs, in general. (1) and (2) are the **only sources** I found that give an expression or algorithm to compute values in that spectrum. Are there **other sources** that you may be aware of?

**EDIT:** this second question doesn't really make sense, because $0$ is in the spectrum of the infinite $(3,2)$-regular tree.
A second question is that, while trying to apply the algorithm described in (1) to the $(3,2)$-complete bipartite graph, I wasn't able to see why $0$ is not in the spectrum (of the adjacency operator) of the infinite $(3,2)$-biregular tree. So,

- What should be the ratio system $\{ r_e\}$, so that the corresponding Perron eigenvalue $\alpha(r) < 1$?
- Given that $r_e = \frac{G(u,v)}{G(u,u)}$, with $e = (u,v)$, and the Green function is invariant under automorphisms of the base graph, can we assume that $r_e$ is also invariant under the same automorphisms?
- Is the Green function associated to the adjacency operator unique? And does that say that the, if it exists, the ratio systems are unique?

[image: (3,2)-complete bipartite graph]

I appreaciate any insight from people, because computing this simple example has got me very confused. Thank you in advance!

Comment: My second question was incorrect, because $0$ is, in fact, in the spectrum of infinite $(3,2)$-biregular tree, so there should exist any ratio system $\{ r_e \}$ such that $\alpha(r) < 1$. Moreover, it is true that when such ratio system exists, there is also one ratio system (perhaps the same) which is invariant under automorphisms.
I would still like to see some literature suggestion, if anyone has relevant suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the paper "Combinatorics of Free Product Graphs" by Quenell, which gives a very friendly and readable account of the determination of the spectrum of free product graphs.  Since many non-regular infinite trees are (basically) free product graphs, you might get some use out of it.

*Quenell, Gregory*, Combinatorics of free product graphs, Brooks, Robert (ed.) et al., Geometry of the spectrum. 1993 joint summer research conference on spectral geometry, July 17-23, 1993, Univ. of Washington, Seattle, USA. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society. Contemp. Math. 173, 257-281 (1994). [ZBL0808.05066](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0808.05066).